# "TS2769: No overload matches this call" Using fetch in fullcalendar with react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm learning react and typescript but I'm struggling with theses two errors and how to fix them;

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: CalendarOptions | Readonly<CalendarOptions>): FullCalendar', gave the following error.
> Type '(info: { start: Date; end: Date; startStr: string; endStr: string; timeZone: string; }, successCallback: (events: EventInput[]) => void, failureCallback: (error: EventSourceError) => void) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'EventSourceInput | undefined'.
> Type '(info: { start: Date; end: Date; startStr: string; endStr: string; timeZone: string; }, successCallback: (events: EventInput[]) => void, failureCallback: (error: EventSourceError) => void) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'EventSourceFunc'.
> Type 'Promise<void | EventInput[]>' is not assignable to type 'void | PromiseLike<EventInput[]>'.
> Type 'Promise<void | EventInput[]>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<EventInput[]>'.
> Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
> Type '<TResult1 = void | EventInput[], TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: void | EventInput[]) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = EventInput[], TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: EventInput[]) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
> Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'void | EventInput[]' is not assignable to type 'EventInput[]'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'EventInput[]'.
>
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CalendarOptions, context: any): FullCalendar', gave the following error.
> Type '(info: { start: Date; end: Date; startStr: string; endStr: string; timeZone: string; }, successCallback: (events: EventInput[]) => void, failureCallback: (error: EventSourceError) => void) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'EventSourceInput | undefined'.

The error is underlying the props `events`

> <FullCalendar **events**=...

```
import React from 'react'
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'
import '@fullcalendar/react/dist/vdom'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import useRoute from '@/Hooks/useRoute'

export default function Calendar() {
  const route = useRoute()

  return (
    <AppLayout>
            <FullCalendar
              plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
              initialView="dayGridMonth"
              events={(info, successCallback, failureCallback) => {

                interface Body {
                  data: EventInput[]
                }

                return fetch(
                  route('events', {start: info.startStr, end: info.endStr})
                )
                  .then((response: any) => response.json() as Promise<Body>)
                  .then(body => successCallback(body.data))
                  .catch((reason: any) => failureCallback(reason))

              }}
            />
    </AppLayout>
  )
}
```

Thanks!